# PHP: Should I ever use == over ===?

Tags: php

My understanding for a long time was that basically never to use ==, since it doesn't respect type and can end up causing undesired results.

I just read this post about the general comparison
[How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

but wasn't sure if everyone has the same opinion as me.

Here is the scenario which I encountered:

**Original code**

```
$state = (intval($state) === TIMESHEET_STATE_UNLOCKED) ? 'unlock' : 'lock';
```

We had found that this line was invalid, since our constant TIMESHEET_STATE_UNLOCKED was a boolean and $state was the string '0' or '1'. We could fix this in one of two ways:

```
$state = (intval($state) === intval(TIMESHEET_STATE_UNLOCKED)) ? 'unlock' : 'lock';
```

OR

```
$state = ($state == intval(TIMESHEET_STATE_UNLOCKED)) ? 'unlock' : 'lock';
```

My first inclination was to former but I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: The tradeoffs are adequately explained at the post I just linked.  You can decide for yourself.

Comment: I would rather close it as opinion based. My two cents: use === and explicit cast.

Comment: If I'm only expecting an alphanumeric outcome, I use ==, but === when I need to make sure types are the same.